# Why can't I sign in with Google?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I just started playing Pokemon Go and it asks me to sign up with my Google account.  So I press on sign up with Google and the page will not load.  I am connected to the Internet and everything, so why won't it load for me?  plz answer.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience if you make your date of birth to low it will say only sign up with the Pokemon Go Club + Blank out the google sign so you cant login.

But if you get the " No connectivity sign , unable to load " or something like that its not that you have no internet it may be:

To many people are trying to login at that same time
It might be under maintenance/construction. exc.

Hope i helped